# Nginx with mod_security support

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, mod-security

I have compiled nginx with mod_security support. In error log I can see the support for mod_security

> 2012/08/27 11:13:11 [info] 602096#0: ModSecurity for nginx/2.7.0-rc2
>   (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
>
> 2012/08/27 11:13:11 [info] 602096#0: ModSecurity: APR compiled
>   version="1.4.2"; loaded version="1.4.2"
>
> 2012/08/27 11:13:11 [info] 602096#0: ModSecurity: PCRE compiled
>   version="8.2 "; loaded version="8.02 2010-03-19"
>
> 2012/08/27 11:13:11 [info] 602096#0: ModSecurity: Loaded PCRE do not
>   match with compiled!
>
> 2012/08/27 11:13:11 [info] 602096#0: ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled
>   version="2.7.8"

I have loaded the ModSecurityConfig and  ModSecurityEnabled
ModSecurityConfig /usr/local/nginx/conf/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf;
ModSecurityEnabled On;

But I cant make mod_security work.

Attacks can get through and I get no error in log file.

Do i need to add any extra configuration to enable mod_security for ngix?

Note: Im using nginx as reverse proxy

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you that may need a solution to this in the future:

I had to activate mod_security and I did this by adding "SecRuleEngine on" at the head modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf